# What binding options are there for an A3 sketchbook that I can rearrange or add pages to?

Tags: material-selection, tool-selection, book-binding, sketching

I want to start a project sketchbook where I will put all of my existing notes for 1 specific project, separated into different sections, and with a table of contents, to arrange them and have a central point for my notes on that project.

It will mostly be text but will also include process flow diagrams and pasted photos, so I want plain paper without printed lines.

I want it to be A3 size, and I thought of getting a plain A3 sketchbook, but there may be a time where 1 page is not enough for a specific section that is between other full pages, so I wonder what options there are for something so I can add a new page in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own **sketchbook ring binder**:

[image]

That way, new blank A3 pages, as well as coloured index tabs, can easily be added anywhere.
You can perforate new pages yourself using a hole puncher.

If your project files consist of a lot of loose or thick objects, you can also opt for a [binder box](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=binder%20box).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You might want to look at the [Levenger Circa binding system](https://www.levenger.com/circa-326/circa-kits-22678.aspx) that uses a special punch and round discs to produce notebooks with removable pages. There are some clones that go by the generic name disk-binding systems.